# Would an iron bar inside a solenoid repel from sides, given enough space?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is the reason this iron bar levitates at the center of the solenoid that it is repelled at the sides?

[image]

This schematics is the assumed magnetic flux direction and what would cause the iron bar to repel along the sides.

[image]

Comment: These coils are cone shaped and not cylindrical.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the levitation and for the heating of the piece of metal inside the solenoid is the [induction heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_heating):

> > An induction heater consists of an electromagnet, and an electronic oscillator that passes a [high-frequency) alternating current (AC) through the electromagnet. The rapidly alternating magnetic field penetrates the object, generating electric currents inside the conductor called [eddy currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current).

Eddy currents during their formation are directed in opposite to the external field:

> > Eddy currents flow in closed loops within conductors, in planes perpendicular to the magnetic field.

That is why the metal levitates.

Comment: If the eddy currents are induced and the induced polarity is same as polarity of coil, is that not just standard induced electromagnetic field, and eddy currents more used in context for what is heating the metal?

Comment: The idea I had was that the metal bars were aligned at center of transverse plane because of repulsion along sides. Do not understand what else would cause them to align that way (along transverse plane, I understand the forces along longitudinal plane), and it looks like they levitate in center of radial axis.

Comment: So what I assumed was like this --> null point along sides, being reason the metal rods align in center of transverse plane,
https://i.imgur.com/CjiiPNF.png